# How to get Column from Table using Bracket Notation in declarative SQLAlchemy 2.0

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, orm

I use python SQLAlchemy 2.0 ORM in declarative style to define my tables like such:

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import DeclarativeBase
from sqlalchemy import select

class Example(DeclarativeBase):
    __tablename__ = 'example'
    foo = mapped_column(Text, nullable=False)
```

I know that I can access table column in queries using "dot notation":

```
select(Example.foo).select_from(Example)
```

Is there some way to also access tables using "bracket notation"? This might look like the following:

```
select(Example['foo']).select_from(Example)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
select(Example.__table__.c['foo']).select_from(Example)
```